Loop to format all worksheets in workbook
I've written a macro that formats a worksheet in preparation for export to pdf.
Option Explicit

Sub Formatting()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim rng1, rng2, rng3, rng4, ccode As Range
    Dim FinalRow As Long
    Dim chapter As String
    With ws
        'set ws = to sheet1
         Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

        'find the last row of data in column A
        FinalRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        Set rng1 = Range("A3:A" & FinalRow)
    
        rng1.Unmerge
    
        Set rng2 = Range("B3:B" & FinalRow)
        For Each cell In rng2    'For each cell in the selected range, if the cell is empty, set the cell's value to be the same as the cell to the left.
            If cell.Value = "" Then
                cell.Font.Name = cell.Offset(0, -1).Font.Name
                cell.Font.Size = cell.Offset(0, -1).Font.Size
                cell.Font.FontStyle = cell.Offset(0, -1).Font.FontStyle
                Cells.VerticalAlignment = cell.Offset(0, -1).VerticalAlignment
                cell.Value = cell.Offset(0, -1).Value
            End If
        Next cell
             
        Set rng3 = Range("A:A")
        rng3.EntireColumn.Delete
        Set rng4 = Range("A:A")
        rng4.EntireRow.AutoFit
        
        chapter = Range("A" & FinalRow)
        Range("D3").Value = Mid(chapter, 44, 4)
        Range("D3").Font.Name = "Arial"
        Range("D3").Font.Size = "8"
        ws.Name = Range("D3")
    End With
     
End Sub

I need to loop through all sheets in the workbook before exporting them all.
I think the issue is here:
'set ws = to sheet1
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Since that needs to be dynamic as it loops through the sheets.

Something like this should work:
Sub Formatting()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, cell As Range, FinalRow As Long, chapter As String
    Dim c2 As Range
    
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        FinalRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
        ws.Range("A3:A" & FinalRow).UnMerge
    
        'For each cell in the range, if the cell is empty, set
        '    the cell's value to be the same as the cell to the left.
        For Each cell In ws.Range("B3:B" & FinalRow).Cells
            With cell
                If .Value = "" Then
                    Set c2 = .offset(0, -1) 'cell to the left of `cell`
                    .Font.Name = c2.Font.Name
                    .Font.Size = c2.Font.Size
                    .Font.FontStyle = c2.Font.FontStyle
                    .VerticalAlignment = c2.VerticalAlignment
                    .Value = c2.Value
                End If
            End With
        Next cell
          
        ws.Range("A:A").EntireColumn.Delete
        ws.Range("A:A").EntireRow.AutoFit
        
        chapter = ws.Range("A" & FinalRow).Value
        With ws.Range("D3")
            .Value = Mid(chapter, 44, 4)
            .Font.Name = "Arial"
            .Font.Size = "8"
            ws.Name = .Value
        End With
    Next ws
End Sub


You can't set Name property of a Workbook, you can only use SaveAs to rename it.

Use Formatting Code For All Sheets
Before

After

All
Sub FormatAllWorksheets()

    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Format All Worksheets"

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    ' If it's the workbook containing this code use 'Set wb = ThisWorkbook'!!!

    Dim ws As Worksheet, Count As Long, TotalCount As Long
    Dim WasSuccess As Boolean ' set by 'FormatSingleWorksheet'

    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        TotalCount = TotalCount + 1
        FormatSingleWorksheet ws, WasSuccess, True
        If WasSuccess Then Count = Count + 1
    Next ws

    MsgBox Count & " out of " & TotalCount & " sheet" _
        & IIf(TotalCount = 1, "", "s") & " " & IIf(Count = 1, "was", "were") _
        & " successfully formatted.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE

'    ' If you're not interested in the info (message boxes) provided, use:
'    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
'        FormatSingleWorksheet ws
'    Next ws
'    ' ... and remove the redundant code (variables and message box).

End Sub

Single
Sub FormatSingleWorksheet( _
        ByVal ws As Worksheet, _
        Optional ByRef WasSheetSuccesfullyFormatted As Variant, _
        Optional ByVal ShowFailMessage As Boolean = False)
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Format Single Worksheet"
    On Error GoTo ClearError ' start error-handling routine

    ' Reset the success flag. Note the 'ByRef' above indicating that this
    ' will be set in the calling procedure.
    If Not IsMissing(WasSheetSuccesfullyFormatted) Then
        WasSheetSuccesfullyFormatted = False
    End If

    ' Define constants.

    Const SOURCE_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "A3"
    Const DST_COLUMN As String = "B"
    Const CHAPTER_COLUMN As String = "D" ' (after deleting column 'A')
    Const CHAPTER_START As Long = 44
    Const CHAPTER_LENGTH As Long = 4
    Const CHAPTER_FONT_NAME As String = "Arial"
    Const CHAPTER_FONT_SIZE As Long = 8

    ' Reference the source single-column range.

    Dim srg As Range, RowsCount As Long

    With ws.Range(SOURCE_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS)
        RowsCount = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
        If RowsCount < 1 Then ' no data in column
            If ShowFailMessage Then
                MsgBox "No data found in ""'" & ws.Name & "'!" _
                    & .Resize(ws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1).Address(0, 0) & """!", _
                    vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
            End If
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set srg = .Resize(RowsCount)
    End With

    srg.UnMerge

    ' Replace blanks in the destination column
    ' with the values in the source column and format.

    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = srg.EntireRow.Columns(DST_COLUMN)
    Dim ColumnOffset As Long: ColumnOffset = srg.Column - drg.Column

    Dim scell As Range, dcell As Range

    For Each dcell In drg.Cells
        If Len(CStr(dcell.Value)) = 0 Then
            Set scell = dcell.Offset(, ColumnOffset)
            With dcell
                .Font.Name = scell.Font.Name
                .Font.Size = scell.Font.Size
                .Font.FontStyle = scell.Font.FontStyle
                .VerticalAlignment = scell.VerticalAlignment
                .Value = scell.Value
            End With
        End If
    Next dcell

    ' Delete the source column.

    srg.EntireColumn.Delete xlShiftToLeft

    ' Autofit the destination column.

    drg.EntireRow.AutoFit
    ' Or!?
    'ws.UsedRange.EntireRow.AutoFit

    ' Extract the 'Chapter' from the last destination cell.

    Dim Chapter As String: Chapter = CStr(drg.Cells(RowsCount).Value)
    Chapter = Mid(Chapter, CHAPTER_START, CHAPTER_LENGTH)

    With drg.Cells(1).EntireRow.Columns(CHAPTER_COLUMN)
        .Value = Chapter
        .Font.Name = CHAPTER_FONT_NAME
        .Font.Size = CHAPTER_FONT_SIZE
    End With

    ' Rename the sheet.

    On Error Resume Next ' defer error handling (ignore errors)
        ws.Name = Chapter
    On Error GoTo ClearError ' restart error-handling routine

    If ws.Name <> Chapter Then
        If ShowFailMessage Then
            MsgBox "Could not rename sheet """ & ws.Name & """ to """ _
                & Chapter & """!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        End If
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Set the success flag (in the calling procedure).

    If Not IsMissing(WasSheetSuccesfullyFormatted) Then
        WasSheetSuccesfullyFormatted = True
    End If

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
ClearError: ' continue error-handling routine
    If ShowFailMessage Then
        MsgBox "Run-time error [" & Err.Number & "]:" & vbLf & vbLf _
            & Err.Description, vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
    End If
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub

Message Boxes


